# Firefox 59 service worker hangs when it receives a 302 redirect (only when throttled)

Tags: firefox, service-worker, http-redirect, http-status-code-302

I have a progressive web application that uses sw-toolbox which is having an issue in Firefox (versions 59, 58 and probably prior to that as well)

The problem does not extend to Chrome, only Firefox is affected.

When the web server (IIS 10 in this case) returns a 302 response, Firefox does not follow it **when network throttling to "Regular 3G" or slower is enabled** The browser just remains on the original location. In fact the tab becomes useless as you cant navigate anywhere from it any longer, you need to open a new tab.

Here is what I am seeing in the network tab of F12 tools:

[image]

Its consistently reproducible, it will happen every time... but as soon as you disable throttling, it all works absolutely fine.

I suspect its an issue in the service worker's (sw-toolbox's) FETCH method but not sure how to debug it.

Comment: If you can make this easily reproducible by anyone, I'd go ahead and open up a bug report [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi)